# what exactly is an entry visa?

Tags: visas, taiwan

I intend to attend an international conference in Taiwan this September and was looking into the visa procedure for the same. The website (https://www.boca.gov.tw/cp-152-274-8c0e2-2.html) says that if I have a "valid entry visa" to US, I can apply for an e-visa, which seems to be an easier way out. I do have a valid B-1/B-2 visa and a J-1 visa that expired 7-8 months ago, but I've never heard the term "entry visa" before. A google search doesn't explain anything either. Therefore, what exactly is an "entry visa"?

Comment: I'd imagine it is any visa that allows you entry into the said country.

Comment: @RedBaron I'd guess that too, but since this is international travel we're talking about, I don't want to risk anything.

Comment: The same applies for Mexico where I you get a visa exemption by showing a valid B-1/B-2 visa or any European Schenguen visa. In your case I guess you can just apply for the evisa, given your US visa is valid at the time of your travel to Taiwan. but here is the wrong place to get a definitive answer, call or email the Taiwanese Embassy in your country or in any neighboring country.

Comment: @EkdeepSinghLubana I think the best people to answer this would be the embassy staff of Taiwan. Note that they accept "expired visas" that have expired less than 10 years ago so you should be fine even if you don't have a valid "entry visa".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An "entry visa" is just a visa which permits you to travel to the named countries.

It is written this way to distuingish it from the ["exit visa"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Travel_visa#Exit_visas), which is a document that a few countries still use, which is required for a person to leave those countries.

Comment: In other words, for the term "entry visa" is effectively a synonym for "visa."